# XML Remove node without changing other nodes

Tags: java, xml

Here is my code. It removes cubes comparing cube attribute "name" against a value I passed as a variable to the method.
But the issue is it change other nodes (dimension,other ) in the xml file.

```
<schema>
    <dimension..../>
    <cube name="..." .../>
    <others ..>
</schema>
```

What I can do to prevent other nodes getting changed ?

```
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();
String expressionQuery = String.format("//Schema/Cube[@name=\"%s  \"]",cubeName);
XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(expressionQuery);

Node nodeToRemove = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
if(nodeToRemove != null) {
    nodeToRemove.getParentNode().removeChild(nodeToRemove);
}
```

Comment: Changes in what way?

Comment: sort attributes to alphabetic order.

Comment: Why is that a problem??

Comment: We prefer name attribute as the first attribute in the node. In our scenario it is like a unique identification value. If the name attribute go to the middle of the element it would be difficult to read